# Pop out element with parent as position: relative and overlow-y:auto

Tags: css, overflow, css-position

I have a container `.content` which has `position:relative` and `overflow-y:auto`, and this children `.box` (which is a squared blue box) has `position:absolute`. Even I have defined `top:-50px` to the `.box`, this element is not fully showed. How can I make it fully visible?

This is my HTML:

```
<div class="content">
  <h1>Hello world</h1>
  <h1>Hello world</h1>
  <h1>Hello world</h1>
  <h1>Hello world</h1>
  <h1>Hello world</h1>
  <h1>Hello world</h1>
  <h1>Hello world</h1>
  <h1>Hello world</h1>
  <div class="box">OTHER BOX</div>
</div>
```

And the correspondent CSS:

```
.content{
  margin-top: 50px;
  background: red;
  height: 250px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  position: relative;
}

.box{
  position: absolute;
  background: blue;
  color: white;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  top: -50px;
}
```

**IMPORTANT**: in this specific case it is required for `.content` to be `relative` positioned and `overflow-y: auto`

Here's a JSFiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/4ooa9L7g/6/

Answer (score 0):

You can try to set `top: 0px;` in place of `top: -50px;` in box class css. After that your `.box` element will fully show

Comment: Jasbir, in this scenario the box element needs to be visible outside the content, but being its child.